# "No fiber running" while trying to parse a csv line by line

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, node-fibers

I'm trying to understand how I can use a Fiber within fast-csv to make a line-by-line reader (single user command line script) that pauses reading/processing at each line until that line has completed a variety of async calls.  (without rolling my own csv code, I want to use something that has already figured out the gotchas with respect to csv formatting)

If I do this

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");

var CSV_STRING = 'a,b\n' +
'a1,b1\n' +
'a2,b2\n';

csv
.fromString(CSV_STRING, {headers: false})
.on("record", function (data) {
    console.log("line="+JSON.stringify(data));
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("timeout");
    },2000);
})
.on("end", function () {
    console.log("done parsing CSV records");
});
console.log("done initializing csv parse");
```

I get what I expect:

```
done initializing csv parse
line=["a","b"]
line=["a1","b1"]
line=["a2","b2"]
done parsing CSV records
timeout
timeout
timeout
```

If I try to use a Fiber to yield after each record

```
Fiber(
    function () {
        var fiber = Fiber.current;

        csv
            .fromString(CSV_STRING, {headers: false})
            .on("record", function (data) {
                console.log("line="+JSON.stringify(data));
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("timeout");
                    fiber.run();
                },2000);
                Fiber.yield();
            })
            .on("end", function () {
                console.log("done parsing CSV records");
            });
        console.log("done initializing csv parse");
    }).run();
```

I get

```
done initializing csv parse
line=["a","b"]
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: yield() called with no fiber running
```

I think I understand what is happening, that the code in the Fiber().run() finishes so it leaves the fiber before a yield is called, so when it gets to the yield there is no longer a fiber. (hence the clever error message "no fiber running")

**What would be an appropriate way for me to keep the fiber running until I'm done parsing?**

Seems like such a simple question but I'm not seeing the obvious answer?  At first I thought of putting a yield right before it leaves the Future().run(), but that doesn't work because the first fiber.run() would make it leave the fiber again.

What I'm wanting is for the flow to be like:

```
done initializing csv parse
line=["a","b"]
timeout
line=["a1","b1"]
timeout
line=["a2","b2"]
timeout
done parsing CSV records
```

**but maybe that isn't possible without reworking the inside of fast-csv since it controls when the events get fired for each record.  My current line of thinking is one would have to yield at the point each each event is fired inside fast-csv and let the user handling the event in csv.on("record") give control back to the loop parsing the csv in fast-csv.**

Answer (score 0):

Node: v5.4.0

Well, here is one way to get that kind of behavior.  I used es6 generators to read the raw file line-by-line then used a generator on the fast-csv library to parse the raw string from line-by-line reads which results in a non-async execution flow and output resembling old single user command line scripts.

```
'use strict';
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var sfs = require('./sfs');

function parse(line) {
    csv
        .fromString(line, {headers: false})
        .on("record", function (data) {
            it.next(data);
        });
}

function *main() {
    // Make sure to initialize with a max buffer big enough to span any possible line length.  Otherwise undefined
    var fs = new sfs(it, 4096);
    var result=yield fs.open("data.csv");

    var line;

    while((line=yield fs.readLine()) != null) {
        console.log("line="+line);

        var csvData=yield parse(line);
        console.log("value1="+csvData[0]+" value2="+csvData[1]);
    }

    console.log("DONE");
}

var it = main();
it.next(); // get it all started
```

Along with a quacky (quick and hacky) class to wrap the fs stuff I needed.  I'm sure there is a much much better way to do what I did, but it works for my needs.

sfs.js

```
'use strict';
var fs=require('fs')

class sfs {
    constructor(it, maxbufsize) {
        this.MAX_BUF=maxbufsize;
        this.it=it;
        this.fd=null;
        this.lineBuf="";
        this.buffer=new Buffer(this.MAX_BUF);
        this.buflen=0;
    }

    open(file) {
        var parent=this;
        fs.open(file,'r',function(err,fd){
            parent.fd=fd;
            var parent2=parent;
            fs.fstat(fd,function(err, stats){
                parent2.stats=stats;
                parent2.it.next(stats);
            })
        })

    }

    readLine(){
        var parent = this;
        var i=0
        var s=this.stats.size
        var line="";
        var index=this.MAX_BUF-this.buflen;

        // read data into buffer, buffer may already have data from previous read that was shifted left over extracted line
        fs.read(this.fd,this.buffer,this.MAX_BUF-index,index,null,function(err,len,buf){
            var expectedReadLen=parent.MAX_BUF-parent.buflen;
            if(len < expectedReadLen) {  // If we didn't read enough to backfill buffer, lets make sure the string is terminated
                // as it shifts left so we don't try interpret older records to the right
                parent.buffer.fill(' ',parent.buflen+len,parent.MAX_BUF);
            }
            parent.buflen+=len; // whatever was in buffer has more now

            index=parent.buffer.indexOf('\n');

            if(index > -1) {
                line=parent.buffer.toString('utf8',0,index);
                buf.copy(parent.buffer,0,index+1,parent.buflen); // shift unused data left
                parent.buflen-=(index+1); // buffer left over after removing /n terminated line
                if(len<expectedReadLen) {  // If we didn't read enough to backfill buffer, lets make sure we erase old data
                    parent.buffer.fill(' ',parent.buflen,parent.MAX_BUF);
                }
            } else {
                if(parent.buflen > 0) {
                    line=parent.buffer.toString('utf8',0,parent.buflen);
                    parent.buflen=0;
                } else {
                    line=null;
                }
            }
            parent.it.next(line);
        });
    }

    close() {
        fs.close(this.fd);
    }
}

module.exports=sfs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams are pausable/resumable:

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");

var CSV_STRING = 'a,b\n' +
    'a1,b1\n' +
    'a2,b2\n';

var stream = csv.fromString(CSV_STRING, { headers: false })
    .on("data", function (data) {
        // pause the stream
        stream.pause();
        console.log("line: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        setTimeout(function () {
            // all async stuff are done, resume the stream
            stream.resume();
            console.log("timeout");
        }, 2000);
    }).on("end", function () {
        console.log("done parsing CSV records");
    });
```

Console output is almost exactly what you want:

```
/*
line: ["a","b"]
timeout
line: ["a1","b1"]
timeout
line: ["a2","b2"]
done parsing CSV records
timeout
*/
```

Can I ask why you absolutely need to read your csv synchronously?

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting but ran into the issue that pause doesn't guarantee a pause.  In fact in my case 20+ events fired before it paused.  Then noticed in the docs "Note that this doesn't immediately pause the stream of events. Several events may be emitted after calling pause, including line.
"

Comment: As to why:  Maybe it's the old school in me, but when I create a single user script, I don't want parallel execution in many cases.  From a debug standpoint I find it to be a nightmare for batch type jobs.  In some cases I have a significant amount of work to be done on one record before moving on, and if there is a problem.  As it is, I might have 100,000 events queued up all pounding resources.  I just want to handle one request a time.  The generator solution seems to be just what I want.  It seems be handling DB queries, network call and other async stuff just fine.  Thanks for input!

Comment: one final note.  I'm not anti-async at all, just in some cases I really prefer sync style execution.

Comment: @sday I see but nodejs is single-threaded, there is no parallel execution. Forcing a sync execution on an async flow like a stream seems counter-productive to me. It will also make the execution time higher. The event queue will not explode, everything will be paused if necessary. I tried with a big 2GB csv file inside a virtual machine with 1GB RAM,  the memory was fully used quickly and the processing slowed but node didn't crash.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what is happening.  If I receive 100 events from the csv library that prompt me to make 100 DB writes that take 100ms each, all 100 events and 100 DB writes calls return in say 50ms, now we wait for the DB callbacks to indicate they have completed right?  Node may have executed it's calls in a singled threaded manner, but they essentially made calls to lower level routines working in a thread of their own working in parallel to the node thread of execution.  Isn't this correct?